# PHP Loop for, and simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, loops, parsing, for-loop

How can I use a loop for with simplexml_load_file to get all data?

```
$meteo = simplexml_load_file('hxxp://dzmeteo.com/weather.xml');
for($i=1;$i<$jours;$i++) {
   $d1_icon_d = $meteo->dayf->day[$i]->part[0]->icon;
   $d1_icon_n = $meteo->dayf->day[$i]->part[1]->icon;
   echo $d1_icon_d;
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are quite close:

```
$meteo = simplexml_load_file('hxxp://dzmeteo.com/weather.xml');
foreach ($meteo->dayf->day as  $day) {
   $d1_icon_d = $day->part[0]->icon;
   $d1_icon_n = $day->part[1]->icon;
   echo $d1_icon_d;
}
```

Any time you want to access the content on an entire array use `foreach`. It provides for a reliable way to ensure you have actually seen all the elements of the array and makes your code readable to yourself and others.

Comment: work fine with   foreach ($meteo->dayf->day as  $day) {

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$i++;` at the end of the loop. The for loop will increment the index for you so as of now you are getting rows 1,3,5,7 and so on instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6. Also I'm not sure if this is deliberate but typically indexes start at 0 and yours starts at 1.

Comment: even removing $i++; it displays nothing